# Android page design editing

Tags: android, editing

I have radio app with scrolling sort view on home screen like this:

https://i.ibb.co/HBwFH2X/1.png

i trying to edit this and make 2 columns with 2 rows like this:

https://i.ibb.co/4J9HZbd/2.png

i dont know how to do that then
if someone have time to help me, i will send everything you need.

````
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/lyt_parent"
    android:layout_width="202dp"
    android:layout_height="320dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="257dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        app:cardElevation="5dp"
        app:cardMaxElevation="0dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/corner_radius"
        card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_radio"
                android:layout_width="199dp"
                android:layout_height="257dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/img_content_description"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_thumbnail"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,2:1.3"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>```
````